# Find instances of matching elements in TWO different columns (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns (id and course_id).

I want to find instances in which there are duplicate entries across BOTH columns.  So, if it's.....

id | course_id
--------------
4  |  56
5  |  56
6  |  31
6  |  43
6  |  31

I would want to know about the duplicate 6  |  31.

Is there a query that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
id,course_id
from table
group by
id,course_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sqlfiddle to play with and the query below

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60874/10

```
SELECT id, course_id, count(*) as 'count' FROM tbl_name GROUP BY id, course_id HAVING `count` > 1;
```